# Rails - File upload with Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to upload a file and parse it to rails. I also want to put the content of the file in a sortable table. I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true and got through it.

My View file - index.html.erb looks like this -

```
<%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do %>
Import a file
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

*_controllers.rb looks like this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @users = User.order(params[:sort])
 end 

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def import
  User.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to action: 'index'
 end
end
```

Now I want to add styling to the file upload button using Javascript/Bootstrap. I changed the index.html.erb to the following -

```
<%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do %>
<span class="fileUpload btn btn-primary"> Upload
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
</span>
<%= submit_tag "Submit">
<% end %>
```

and now assets/javascripts/*.js looks like this -

```
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function() {
document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

This is not working because the uploaded file is not being parsed as ':file' is not assigned anything.

How can I apply CSS and javascript styling to 'file_field_tag'?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be able to add css styling to the tag the same way you could use for your form helpers as such:

   `file_field_tag :file, class: 'whatever-class'`
2. While using your hand-written file input, I think you're not getting a value in your controller because you didn't name your field, fix should be simple as:

   `<input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name='file' />`
3. I know you can upload file via AJAX/JS but I don't think the process is that straight-forward as I think you'd need to do some custom form serializations using `FormData` and other stuff like that. Not totally confident that I'm right though!

Comment: I tried it however it did not work. It did not pick my css stylesheet. It doesnot throw any error when I include my css file but it just doesnot apply the css styling defined inside .css